# How to test an Flask API that is using context arguments

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I'm pretty new at programming and I'm blocked trying to create an unit test for this application, its pretty simple:

```
from flask import Flask, request,jsonify,make_response

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/header')
def my_route():
    text = request.args.get('text')
    tag = request.args.get('tag',default=0,type=int)
    if text.find('.')==-1:
        if tag==0:
            return jsonify(header=text.title())
        else:          
            return jsonify(header= '<h' + str(tag) + '>' + text.title() + '</h' + str(tag) + '>' ) # HTML TAG
    else:
        return make_response(jsonify(error='Dots are not allowed in headers'),400) #BAD REQUEST ERROR 400


if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

I've tried something like this:

```
from main import app
from flask import json

def test_my_route():        
    response = app.test_client().get(
        '/header?text=Hello',
    )

    assert response.status_code == 200
```

But it doensn't work , It think that the problem i  that I'm using context arguments for the query string and not the actual function ones. Can I get any help with this?

Thank you!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: 404 not found..

Comment: Could you please add the stacktrace to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue may be that you're trying to run the test client outside of it's application context.

Try wrapping your call within the application context:

```
def test_my_route(): 

    with app.app_context():

        response = app.test_client().get(
            '/header?text=Hello',
        )

        assert response.status_code == 200
```

If you're running a unittest suite then best to put this in your setup - this is my `setUp` and `tearDown` functions for my `BaseTestClass` that all my other unit tests inherit from (`create_app` is just my usual application factory, you can probably just import `app` from your other module):

```
from unittest import TestCase
from app.application import create_app, db

class BaseTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        self.app = create_app()
        self.db = db

        self.app.config['TESTING'] = True

        self.app_context = self.app.app_context()
        self.app_context.push()
        self.client = self.app.test_client()

    def tearDown(self):

        self.db.session.remove()
        self.db.get_engine(self.app).dispose()
        self.app_context.pop()
```